# restful service attempt gives build error that i am unable to decipher

Tags: java, spring

I'm following the spring.io tutorial on building a restful service. (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).
I run the application with gradlew bootRun.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2020-02-14 13:21:59.768  INFO 9504 --- [           main] c.e.restservice.RestServiceApplication   : Starting RestServiceApplication on DESKTOP-6L8BU2S with PID 9504 (C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\rest-service\build\classes\java\main started by Gebruiker in C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\rest-service)
2020-02-14 13:21:59.770  INFO 9504 --- [           main] c.e.restservice.RestServiceApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-14 13:22:00.630  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-02-14 13:22:00.641  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-14 13:22:00.642  INFO 9504 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2020-02-14 13:22:00.723  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-14 13:22:00.723  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 888 ms
2020-02-14 13:22:00.904  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-14 13:22:01.024  INFO 9504 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-02-14 13:22:01.029  INFO 9504 --- [           main] c.e.restservice.RestServiceApplication   : Started RestServiceApplication in 1.57 seconds (JVM running for 1.943)
2020-02-14 13:23:10.145  INFO 9504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-02-14 13:23:10.145  INFO 9504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-02-14 13:23:10.153  INFO 9504 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
<=========----> 75% EXECUTING [9m 1s]                                                                                                                                                                                                        > :bootRun
```

This gives me a Whitelabel Error Page, my intelliJ IDEA gives me an error when building the application, but I don't know what to do about this error because it gives little information:

[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RMsX.png)

[image: build error]

Comment: what is the actual error?

Comment: You mean when i uncollapse the complete error at the right side of the screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it might version incompatibility between Gradle and IntelliJ.

Try updating IntelliJ to latest version.

Comment: updating to IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 (Ultimate Edition) seemed to do the trick